# How to register service provider in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to build my own code repository for my application in laravel 5.3 installation. I created following folder Nitseditor in the root folder of the laravel installed directory, then changed the following into composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "NitsEditor\\": "NitsEditor/"
    }
```

I created a service provider into the providers folder i.e. `Nitseditor\Providers\DomainServiceProvider`

```
namespace Nitseditor\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DomainServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register to check domain subscription status
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function register()
    {
        $this->checkDomainName();
        $this->app->singleton('domain', function()
        {
            return $this->domain;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Checking domain status
     */
    public function checkDomainName()
    {
        $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        return $domain;
    }

}
```

Then I changed following in `config\app.php`

```
/*
 * Nitseditor Service Providers...
*/

Nitseditor\Providers\DomainServiceProvider::class
```

Then I did `composer dump-autoload`

I'm getting `FatalThrowableError` following is the screenshot

[image]

Help me out.

Comment: check the namespace of your class

Comment: Try to first run 'composer dump-autoload' then add it in app.php

Comment: issue with your namespace

Comment: I found out the mistake. It was silly. I typed `"NitsEditor\\": "NitsEditor/"` but it should be `"Nitseditor\\": "Nitseditor/"` uppercase lowercase mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed "NitsEditor\": "NitsEditor/" but it should be "Nitseditor\": "Nitseditor/" uppercase lowercase mistake, which solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to me you should clear your cache.

Follow these steps:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` is throwing error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Nitseditor\Providers\DomainServiceProvider' not found`

Comment: Make sure you've provided the correct directory & namespace to your `DomainServiecProvider`

Comment: I've included the service provider file in question. I've written correct namespace too. Please review.

Comment: In which directory path you've placed this provider file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131520/discussion-between-saumya-rastogi-and-nitish-kumar).

Comment: I found out the mistake. It was silly. I typed `"NitsEditor\\": "NitsEditor/"` but it should be `"Nitseditor\\": "Nitseditor/"` uppercase lowercase mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Remove provider from `app.php`, run `composer dumpauto` command, return it in `app.php`.

This will work if namespace is correct.

Comment: I tried it, but its not working. I've inserted the service provider which I've made. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

Publish the Service Provider which is added in app.php

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Also, if you have helpers.php in the directory you have added, make sure to include that file in composer.json

for an example

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "Spatie\\Permission\\": "Spatie/",
            "Kalnoy\\Nestedset\\": "Kalnoy/"
        },
        "files": [
            "Spatie/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```